# Problema no checkin no VisualStudio 2012

Tags: visual-studio, team-foundation-server, visual-studio-2012

Ao tentar fazer o checkin a seguinte mensagem é exibida:

***Check-in validation failed. A policy warning override reason and/or a check-in note is required.***

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Achei que era problema porque faltava comentário mas mesmo adicionando no checkin o erro permanece.

Answer (score 1):

Desce até o final da janela de "Pending Changes", tem um campo chamado "Notes", insira o comentário do checkin lá também. :D